# Spark 2.31 custom non ambari installation on HDP performance issue

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, hdp

I have Spark 2.3.1 custom non ambari installation on HDP 2.6.2 running on a cluster. I have made all the necessary configuration as per the spark and non ambari installation guides.

Now when I submit the spark job in Yarn cluster mode, I see huge gap of 10-12 minutes between the jobs and I do not see any error or operation that are being performed between the jobs. Attached screenshot shows the delay of close to 10 minutes between the jobs and this is leading to unnecessary delay in completing the Spark job.
[Spark 2.3.1 job submitted in Yarn Cluster mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NokW2.jpg)

I have checked the Yarn logs and Spark UI and I do not see any errors or any operations logged with the timestamp between the jobs.

Looking through the event timeline I see the gap of 10 +minutes between the jobs. 
[Event timeline gap between the jobs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GON5.jpg)

Need help in providing any pointers to know how to fix this issue and improve the performance of the job.

Regards,
Vish